# How to use Interactions in InputSystem in Unity continuously?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im now creating a small 2D game with Touch inputs. im trying to create move, shoot and aim controls. i thought of using a single tap to move, to aim i want to press the screen and hold, and to shoot a simple double tap on the screen. unforutnately when i implemented this using the InputSystem module the actions are running only once. and they are not resetting back when im not pressing the screen. How to reset this?

Without the interactions, the movement of the player is good. but the user cant differentiate between the controls of a aim and a move. so inorder for the player to get this difference i tried to use interactions. when i implemented this, the method is only working once.
[A photo of my InputSystem without adding the interactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XjnF.png)
The logic behind every function is perfect, as i implemented these functions without the inputsystem module.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit / differentiate between actions with the same bindings via the `Interactions` modifiers where you can adjust things like press with a certain duration, tap with a certain maximum press duration etc.

See [Interactions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.5/manual/Interactions.html) and in particular [Predefined Interactions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.5/manual/Interactions.html#predefined-interactions)

> - Press
> - Hold
> - Tap
> - SlowTap
> - MultiTap
>   [image]

If you then further want some continuous event every frame afaik you need to e.g. use the HOLD interaction and then

- listen to the `performed` of the action
- set a flag
- if flag is set fire event every frame
- listen to end of action
- reset flag -> stops firing event

According to the image above

Something like e.g.

```
public class InputHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isMoving;

    public event Action whileMoving;

    private void Awake()
    {
        var inputActions = new YourInputActionsClass();

        inputActions.YourActionMap.Move.performed += OnMoveStarted;
        inputActions.YourActionMap.Move.canceled += OnMoveEnded;
    }

    private void OnMoveStarted(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        isMoving = true;
    }

    private void OnMoveEnded(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        isMoving = false;
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if(isMoving) whileMoving?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Then you would rather subscribe to the already processed `whileMoving` event which will be fired each frame while the Moving action is triggered

Comment: when I'm implementing this, I get a problem with InputAction.CallbackContext. it says that the methods "OnMoveStarted" and "OnMoveEnded" should have InputAction.CallbackContext. And writing InputAction.CallbackContext in the function made only the OnMoveEnded function to work. OnMoveStarted isn't getting executed.